# TZ (timezone) doesn't work in "/etc/crontab"

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos

I've tried setting the timezone as:

```
export TZ=Europe/Paris
```

and as:

```
TZ=Europe/Paris
```

But none of them work.

The server is setup for `UTC` time. And it needs to remain that way.

My job needs to happen at `4:00am` (`Paris` time) when the server it not being used. However it happens at `6:00am` (because `UTC` time).

How can I fix this?

Comment: set your `cron` to run at 2 am https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-france-paris

Comment: @nbari Hehe I know about that...I was trying to see if I can solve it with multiple timezones.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/374284/crontab-schedule-in-different-timezones On CentOS, cron does support multiple time zones through `CRON_TZ`

Comment: @marcolz So I must add the timezone before each line, even though it could be the same timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is flagged with CentOS, I assume that you use `cron` from  CentOS:

https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/5/crontab/

Use the `CRON_TZ` variable before a section of rules that you want to run scheduled based on a different time zone.

If you want the commands themselves use that same TZ, then you need to add that to the rules manually.

Comment: Can `CRON_TZ ` be used multiple times? Or just once at the beginning?

Comment: Not sure, at least once per file, according to the manual page. I don't have a CentOS install to test this on, but you do...

Comment: Yes, `CRON_TZ` can be used multiple times in a cron file. See https://serverfault.com/a/1043453/537953